# React Native Redux State not persistent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am using react native with react-native-navigation. When I move from page one to page two my state changes don't persist.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import Home from './home/home';
import Recommend from './recommend/recommend';
import store from '../redux/store';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    Recommend: { screen: Recommend }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <RootStack />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

reduer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { DATA_AVAILABLE, UPDATE_PREFERANCE } from '../actions/index';

const dataState = { data: { college: 'ABC', major: '123' } };

const dataReducer = (state = dataState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case DATA_AVAILABLE:
            state = Object.assign({}, state);
            return state;
        case UPDATE_PREFERANCE:
            console.log('update pref');
            return {
              ...state,
              data: {
                college: action.payload.collegeName,
                major: action.payload.majorName
              }
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    dataReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Home component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Title,
  Content,
  Text,
  Button,
  Icon,
  Footer,
  FooterTab,
  Left,
  Right,
  Item,
  Input,
  View,
  Picker
} from 'native-base';

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import styles from './style';
import * as Actions from '../../redux/actions/index';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      college: '',
      major: ''
    };
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    this.yearList = [];
    this.yearList.push(currentYear);
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      this.yearList.push(currentYear + i);
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getData();
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ college: nextProps.data.college, major: nextProps.data.major });
  }
  onValueChange(value: string) {
    this.setState({
      selected: value
    });
  }
  navigateToRecommend() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Recommend');
  }
  handleChange(text, key) {
    this.setState({ [key]: text });
    this.props.updateUserPreference(this.state.college, this.state.major);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
           ...........render logic
      </Container>
    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
      data: state.dataReducer.data
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

When I move from Home to Recommend page, default state is empty. Also when update preference is called state doesn't change in home component.

EDIT:

store file:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducers from './reducers/index'; //Import the reducer

export default createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Comment: How does your store configuration file looks like?Do you pass preloaded state?Also give us full home component

Comment: There is another parameter to createStore where you can inject your default data.

Also I cannot see where you are dispatching any actions, so i dont know how the reducer would be triggered. One more thing, when you say state doesn't change in home component, do you mean the application state or the local state (i.e. this.state)

Comment: this. handleChange fires this.props.updateUserPreference which triggers action with payload.